# Merge array with same value

Tags: php, arrays

How to marge array result with same value, i was try array_unique but seems does not work for me

Code:

```
$row_content = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$array = unserialize($row_content['content_id']);
foreach($array as $row) {
    print_r($row);

}
```

Here is result

```
Array
(
    [0] => v
    [1] => 2040
)

Array
(
    [0] => v
    [1] => 526
)
Array
(
    [0] => v
    [1] => 200
)

Array
(
    [0] => p
    [1] => 2040
)

Array
(
    [0] => p
    [1] => 600
)
```

Need to merge [1] or 2040 in this example, also value V or P it does not matter here

Edit:

This is what i need to get as result

```
Array
(
    [1] => 200
)
Array
(
    [1] => 526
)
Array
(
    [1] => 600
)
Array
(
    [1] => 2040
)
```

Comment: put your expected output?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Please explain your use case, too, because it seems like you want to fix the sympton of a problem, instead of the problem itself. Maybe add the code that surrounds your foreach loop.

Comment: Actuely that is problem because this number is ID of post, as can you see on this screen i have duplicated posts now https://i.imgur.com/QWmOXYb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your requirements** then this is what you need.

```
<?php
$ar1 = array(array('v',2040),array('v',526),array('v',200),array('v',2040),array('p',600));
$result = [];
foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v){
    $result[]=$v[1];
}
$unique_v = array_unique($result); 
print '<pre>';
print_r($unique_v);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/sGLlc

Comment: Hmm this seems to work fine,also sorting `rsort($unique_v);` is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you are trying to say. But if you want to merge/add all the values of "p" and "v". You can do it like this:

```
$array = array(array('v',2040),array('v',526),array('v',200),array('v',2040),array('p',600));
$keeper = array();

foreach($array as $row){
    if(array_key_exists($row[0],$keeper)){
       $keeper[$row[0]] += $row[1];
    }else{
       $keeper[$row[0]] = $row[1];
    }
}
```